# What delimiters does SAPI TTS use for word parsing?

Tags: parsing, text-to-speech, sapi

Besides a blank space, I can't seem to find documentation on what SAPI TTS uses as delimiters while indexing words in a phrase it is speaking. Does anyone know? Certain punctuation seems to be included, though it seems somewhat situational at times.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language and the voice.  (E.g., in Chinese, spaces aren't word delimiters.)

Within a language, it's really dependent on the TTS engine (aka voice).  SAPI's engine interface for TTS engines is *really* skeletal - two interfaces & 8 methods *total*.  The key interface is [`ISpTtsEngine::Speak`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee413475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  This passes to the engine a linked list of [text fragments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); as you can see from the definition, the properties passed down to it don't contain a delimiter.

By using SSML (pass [`SPF_PARSE_SSML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431843%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to `ISpVoice::Speak`), you can be more explicit about what to speak and not speak.